# How can I make hot keys customizing gui by pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to get custom shortcuts from users.
I want to make a code that records the key entered when I press QpushButton once, stops recording when I press it once again, and stores the entered key in a variable and display it to QLineEdit, readonly.
I tried `import keyboard`, `keyboard.start_record()`, `keyboard.stop_record()` with `clicked.connect()`.
However, I couldn't figure out how this worked.

```
self.pkey = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.play_pause)
    self.pkey.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 161, 21))
    self.pkey.setText("")
    self.pkey.setObjectName("pkey")
    self.pkey.setReadOnly(True)
    

    self.play_pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.play_pause)
    self.play_pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 20, 75, 21))
    p_button_clicked=False
    self.play_pushButton.clicked.connect(button_clicked)

def button_clicked( key, state ):
    if p_button_clicked==False:
        self.play_pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "녹화중"))
        p_button_clicked=True
        keyinput=keyboard.start_record()
    else:
        self.play_pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "단축키 녹화"))
        p_button_clicked=False
        keyinput=keyboard.stop_record()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]